# Sitecore Template Fields Max count

Tags: sitecore

Recently I got required of creating Common data item which will be useful in different component by mapping as data source. This Common data item template is having appx. 40 fields ( single line text, drop down list , custom controls etc ). Based on this new template around 500 ( as per business : 500 different offices ) sitecore items will be created.

Based on above data below components will be implemented : 
Component x : will use 5 fields of the created common data items
Component y : will use 10 fields of the created common data items.
Similarly, in future multiple Components will be created when required.

Search : searching this 500 common data items and display results ( Using Coveo search) will result in any performance issue ?

Is it a good practice to create 40 fields in one template ? will it create any performance issues in future?

Comment: 40 fields is okay for performance. but the idea of the Common data item does not sound clever.

Comment: Completely agree with @JanBluemink - what you're doing is definitely not a recommended approach. The datasource template for a component should hold only the fields the component requires. What this is; is the Sitecore equivalent of "Global Variables" in code - "because you never know when you might need them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be a particular performance issue using this number of fields In a template. However, a better solution might be to break down these 40 fields into separate logical groupings in separate "base" templates (don't let any items use those base templates directly). Then create templates (which your editors would use) inheriting from a number of your base templates. This approach allows you to re-use fields eliminating duplication but also allows you to easily create templates specific for each purpose. It's easier for editors to deal with items containing just the relevant fields as this eliminates ambiguity and confusion.

Comment: Thanks It answered my question.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark as answered if it helped you!